# Can't wait unitil results come back from google API

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I have Two functions : getCoordinate() and getDistance(), both need to make asynchronous request to google apis, the result is a json file,

getDistance:

```
function getDistance(origin,destination,mode)
{
var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?";

var origin="origins="+origin;
var destination="&destinations="+destination;
var mode="&mode="+mode;
var language="&language=fr-FR"
var sensor="&sensor=false";

var def = new jQuery.Deferred(); 
var city;
$.getJSON(url+origin+destination+mode+language+sensor,function(json)
{
    if (json.status=="OK")
    {
    var distance=json.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
    }
    def.resolve(distance);
});
return def.promise();
}
```

And this is getCoordinates:

```
function getCoordinate(address)
{

var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
var sensor="&sensor=false";
var def = new jQuery.Deferred(); 
var city;
$.getJSON(url+address+sensor,function(json)
{
    var lat=json.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var lng=json.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    var dist=google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(myCenter,new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng));
    console.log('address:'+dist/1000+'km');                                                    
    var coord=[lat,lng];
    def.resolve(coord);

});
return def.promise();
}
```

I need use the results of getCoordinate() method inside getDistance(),
but due to the ansynchrous mode getDistance instructions are executed before the results come back from google.

```
   for (i=0;i<addresses.length;i++)
{
$.when(getCoordinate(addresses[i])).then(function (coord) {
var myLatitude=coord[0];
var myLongitude=coord[1];
addressList[j++]=[coord[0],coord[1]];
    $.when(getDistance(lat+","+lng,myLatitude+","+myLongitude,"driving")).then(function(distance)
    {
    var test=i;
    var distTab=[];
    switch(i){
        case 0:
        //do Something
        break;

        default:
        //do something
        break;
          }
        }
    });

});
}       console.log("the dist:"+distance);
    console.log("coordinate:"+myLatitude+","+myLongitude);
    console.log("Center:"+lat+","+lng);
```

Comment: `console.log("the dist:"+distance);` returns different values for every iteration,

but `console.log("coordinate:"+myLatitude+","+myLongitude);` keep giving the same result.

and `i` = 4 witch is the length of `addresses`

Comment: Why don't you let the Distance Matrix do the Geocoding?  You don't have to pass it coordinates, you can use addresses.

Comment: You can use the jQuery `.when()` and `.then()` methods to control async calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using 'google.maps', there are advantages in passing all lat/lng values around as 'google.maps.LatLng' objects.

Also, variables are addressable only when in scope and only once assigned in an async callback, so some of your attempts to `console.log()` are bound to fail.

Applying these principles and tidying up (significantly), I get :

```
function getDistance(origin, destination, mode) {
    //Note: //origin, destination are now google.maps.LatLng objects
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json";
    var data = {
        origin: origin.toUrlValue(),
        destination: destination.toUrlValue(),
        mode: mode,
        language: "fr-FR",
        sensor: "false"
    };
    return $.getJSON(url, data).then(function(json) {
        if(json.status=="OK") {
            return json.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;
        }
        else return $.Deferred().reject().promise();
    });
}

function getCoordinate(address) {
    var url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
    var data = {
        address: address,
        sensor: "false"
    };
    return $.getJSON(url, data).then(function(json) {
        if(json.results && json.results.length && json.results[0].geometry) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                json.results[0].geometry.location.lat,
                json.results[0].geometry.location.lng
            );
            console.log("Center: " + latLng.toString());
            return latLng;
        }
    });
}

for (i=0; i<addresses.length; i++) {
    getCoordinate(addresses[i]).then(function(latLng) {
        console.log("coordinate: " + latLng.toString());
        addressList[j++] = latLng;//now a google.maps.LatLng object
        getDistance(myOrigin, latLng, "driving").then(function(distance) {
            console.log("the dist:" + distance);
            switch(i) {
                case 0: /* do Something */ break;
                default: /* do something */ break;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

*untested*

Of course, this won't work straight out of the box because the rest of your code will need to be adapted to work with `google.maps.LatLng` objects, particularly the variable I have called `myOrigin` (previously `lat` and `lng` in some outer scope) and those in `addressList`.

Comment: The answer is great you must spent some time on it, i haven't tried it yet but i have a question, am i able to get `addressList` value  `getDistance(myOrigin, latLng, "driving").then(function(distance) {`here`}`

Comment: If I understand correctly, then Yes. If `addressList` is within scope of the expression `addressList[j++] ...` then it will automatically be accessible in the `.then()` callback, which is an inner function of the same scope. That rule is inherent to javascript. The only thing that would make `addressList` inaccessible in the inner scope would be to define a "private" `var addressList` in that inner scope.

Comment: What happens is that `i` goes from  `0` to `addresses.length` before the Json response is receveid,

Comment: Yes, as written, the behaviour you describe is absolutely guaranteed, but the `getCoordinate() ... getDistance() ...` sequence of requests will occur for each `address` independently. If you wanted only one sequence of requests to be in progress at a time (ie if you wanted each `address` to wait for the previous `address` to complete) then that's an additional issue that was not part of the question.

Comment: It's academic as you don't have a synchronous solution available to you. All AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: I haven't slept last tree nights to solve this problem but now it's working, thanks to you.

Comment: No worries Hossam. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

Call the second function on success of the first function

```
var getCoordinate() { //call initial function
   $.ajax({
        success: function(results) {
            getDistance(results);//call second function with the results of the first call
        }
   });
};
```

Comment: I still need my Deferred object ?

Comment: I can't get it,  can you make it clearer by naming your functions the as mines