# google places api get details not returned for every place

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-places-api

Hi

I am creating a page on my site which uses the google places api and the user's geo location(lat, lng) and finds nearby restaurants. As part of the code i also look up the distance of the restaurant from the user's location. The issue is while it gets every result and I have a function called getDistance that is called for each place. This is returning empty string for a lot of results and does return it for some. For the purpose of an example i am hardcoding the user's location in this plunker example. Can someone please point out why the distance is not being returned for every place and why its returning an empty string for some and the correct fix for this? I really appreciate your help.

Im calling the get distance function that calculates the distance in miles for each restaurant in the callback function for places service

```
 angular.forEach(results, function(result) {

        //using new function for getting distance from user's location
        var place = getDistance(result, service);

        $scope.places.push(place);
      });
```

Here is the getDistance function

```
function getDistance (place, service) {

    var request = {
      reference: place.reference
    };

    service.getDetails(request, function (details, status) {

        if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

          place.details = details;
          var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween
          (new google.maps.LatLng(33.940496, -84.048816), new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng()));
          var distanceInMiles = getMiles(distance);
          place["distance"] = distanceInMiles;
        }
    });

    return place;
};
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0RY0K0ugOpIfnemndmL3?p=preview)

Comment: Looks like sync issue,  place  is returned before getDetails  callback sets place["distance"] .

Comment: right serg how can i modify this code so the place is not returned until the response comes back from the service.getDetails. I cant do a .then it seems like on the getDetails function, an example of the change would help, thanks!!

Comment: You need promises/deferred objects to get your async request syncronyzed back.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Hi serg, i added a deferred object/promise  to getDistance function and am now adding the place when the promise is resolved but think there's still an issue the distance never gets added and i think the overall no of results are also not being displayed as before. Can you take a look at plunker and let me know if the promised is being resolved correctly before being returned?

Answer (score 2):

Your requests may be subject to blocking if all of your users are making requests at the same time when running client-side geocode requests at periodic intervals. To avoid this, consider one of the following [Quota Considerations](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#quota-limits):

- Use a caching strategy.
- Introduce random intervals to your requests (jitter). Ensure requests
  are random across your entire userbase.
- If developing for Android, use an inexact repeating alarm.
- If developing for Android, select an appropriate location strategy.

The Google Maps API allows you to cache geocodes which can be useful if you repeatedly look up the same address. However, there are two important things to keep in mind as stated in the documentation. One is that:

> Geocoding changes often as our data gets more and more accurate. So even if you have cached data, you should refresh it periodically, to make sure you are getting the best geocodes for your locations.

In addition to providing a list of places within an area, the Places service can also return detailed information about a specific place. Place Details are requested with a call to the service's `getDetails()` method. This method takes a request containing the desired place's `placeId` and also takes a callback method which needs to handle the status code passed in the `google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus` response, as well as the `google.maps.places.PlaceResult` object.

Lastly, for the sync issue, wherein place is returned before `getDetails()` callback sets place, this related SO post - [Can't wait until results come back from google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845100/cant-wait-unitil-results-come-back-from-google-api) can help you.

Comment: Hi Teyam, thanks, So i made a few changes now i have the promises returned so now the distance is returned for every result but the results are limited to only 20-21. You can see the earlier plunker above where there were 60 results. Is this because of a restriction for calls to the getDetails function each time by google? As you see in the init function i wait 2 secs as per requirement of google api to call the  pagination.nextPage() function. Please take a look at this updated plunker and let me know why you think the results are limited http://plnkr.co/edit/9WZnMZ3FGVx5ioVtlkoq?p=preview